# Starting PackageMaker from Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight

Why does Spotlight not allow me to start PackageMaker, although it allow me to start Xcode and Dashcode, which are in the same folder? Any good guides to fixing/modifying this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Snow Leopard, well 10.6.1 you can. Maybe Apple fixed it.